# Create 1-column dataframe from multi-index pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a multi-index series like this:

```py
Year  Month
2012  1        444
      2        222
      3        333
      4        1101
```

which I want to turn into:

```py
Date      Value
2012-01   444
2012-02   222
2012-03   333
2012-04   1101
```

to plot a line.

I have tried both `series.unstack(level=0)` and `series.unstack(level=1)`, but this creates a matrix

```py
In[1]: series.unstack(level=0)
Out[1]: 
Year   2012  2013  2014  2015  2016  2017   2018
Month                                          
1      444  ...   ...   ...   ...   ...    ...
2      222  ...   ...   ...   ...   ...    ...
3      333  ...   ...   ...   ...   ...    ...
4      1101 ...   ...   ...   ...   ...    ...
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Index.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_frame.html) with [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) working if also added `Day` column, and reasign back:

```
s.index = pd.to_datetime(s.index.to_frame().assign(Day=1))
print (s)
2012-01-01     444
2012-02-01     222
2012-03-01     333
2012-04-01    1101
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

For one column `DataFrame` use [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df1 = s.to_frame('Value')
print (df1)
            Value
2012-01-01    444
2012-02-01    222
2012-03-01    333
2012-04-01   1101
```

If need `PeriodIndex` add [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
s.index = pd.to_datetime(s.index.to_frame().assign(Day=1)).dt.to_period('m')
print (s)
2012-01     444
2012-02     222
2012-03     333
2012-04    1101
Freq: M, Name: a, dtype: int64

df2 = s.to_frame('Value')
print (df2)
         Value
2012-01    444
2012-02    222
2012-03    333
2012-04   1101
```

Answer (score 2):

```
idx = pd.PeriodIndex(
    year=s.index.get_level_values(0).tolist(), 
    month=s.index.get_level_values(1).tolist(), 
    freq='M', 
    name='Date'
)
s2 = pd.Series(s.values, index=idx, name=s.name)
s2.plot()
```

You could also use a list comprehension with f-strings to create a DatetimeIndex.

```
idx = pd.to_datetime([f'{year}-{month}' for year, month in s.index])
```